# Como emular o ROW_NUMBER() no MySQL V5.7?

Tags: mysql

Eu sei que essa é uma questão comum e bem documentada em inglês, mas, há pouco dela em português. Então, vou aproveitar a oportunidade e esmiuçar essa dúvida de forma simples e abrangente.

Vamos supor que iremos trabalhar com a tabela abaixo:

```
col_a  | col_b  | prt_x  | prt_y  | ord_u  | ord_w
-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
row_a1 | row_b1 | row_x1 | row_y1 | row_u1 | row_w1
row_a2 | row_b2 | row_x2 | row_y2 | row_u2 | row_w2
row_a3 | row_b3 | row_x3 | row_y3 | row_u3 | row_w3
row_a4 | row_b4 | row_x4 | row_y4 | row_u4 | row_w4
```

E que queremos converter os seguintes comandos nativos do MySQL V8 para o V5.7

1 - ROW_NUMBER COM UM PARTITION BY

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prt_x)
FROM tbl
```

2 - ROW_NUMBER COM DOIS PARTITION BY

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prt_x, prt_y)
FROM tbl
```

3 - ROW_NUMBER COM UM ORDER BY

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prt_x, prt_y, ORDER BY ord_u)
FROM tbl
```

4 - ROW_NUMBER COM DOIS ORDER BY

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prt_x, prt_y, ORDER BY ord_u, ord_v)
FROM tbl
```

5 - ROW_NUMBER COM ORDER BY RAND

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prt_x, prt_y, ORDER BY ord_u, RAND())
FROM tbl
```

6 - ROW_NUMBER COM ORDER BY MOD

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prt_x, prt_y, ORDER BY ord_u, MOD(n1, n2))
FROM tbl
```

Então, como é que poderíamos fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente com variáveis:

```
SET @linha := 0;
SELECT campo1, campo2, @linha := @linha + 1 AS row_number FROM tabela;
```

Se por alguma razão não puder executar o SET separado, pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, @linha := @linha + 1 AS row_number FROM tabela, (SELECT @linha := 0) l;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdc4ee/1)**.

Ainda, se precisar da numeração da tabela virtual, subquery, ou `JOIN`, basta por a variável do outro lado (ou dentro dos parênteses).

Comment: Ham!? Não entendi como fazer. Acho que a minha pergunta é um pouco mais difícil.

Comment: O código acima faz a numeração das linhas, independente da questão da partição. Mas se quiser uma aplicação mais específica, faça um SQL fiddle com o ROW_NUMBER da forma que deseja, que eu posso eventualmente aplicar o conceito acima para você ver usando com PARTITION, assim fica mais fácil de eu entender a dificuldade que teve em aplicar.

Comment: O que eu estou tentando fazer é alguma coisa como isso aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uGebS796L8JVivU2YSFhkh/2 Embora, infelizmente, nesse exemplo o row_number() não instá incrementando a cada linha.